# How to utilize the same spark session in another module

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, airflow

I have to run two modules in Airflow with two tasks. Each task has a PySpark module that does a few spark operations. The second module uses the data frame created in the previous session and continues its operations.
How can we achieve the same with the same `SparkSession` initialized? I have tried with the `getActiveSession()`, but it didn't work since the task 1 job is completed, and hence when task 2 is running, a new spark session is created.

```py
- [root@ ..dags]# cat tmp_spark_1.py

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession    
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PRJT").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (3, 4)], ['a', 'b'])
df.show()

- [root@ ..dags]# cat tmp_spark_2.py

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
#spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PRJT").enableHiveSupport().getActiveSession().getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()
df1 = df.select(df['a'])
df1.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible within two different tasks. Each airlfow task runs potentially in a different process and potentially on a dfferent machine, so when you execute your tasks you need to be aware that their runs are completely isolated from each other and all the connections/sessions etc. opened in memory by one task will not be carried to the second task.

The data between the tasks can only be exchanged by XComs and those are either storing it in a DB or (when you configure Airflow with external storage) in an external storage (such as S3/GCS). There is no sharing of in-memory data between tasks.

This is very basic assumption of Airflow.

If you want to reuse in-memory resources between two different steps, you have to make them a single step in Airflow currently.

There are plans to open up for cases like that in the future - but this is quite far in the future IMHO.